# SharePoint Designer required for InfoPath?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, custom-form

I work in an environment where we don't have anything to edit our SharePoint sites except with JavaScript.  We do have access to InfoPath.  However, there looks like some things we have to do in Designer in order to get the template up to a SharePoint Library.  Is SharePoint Designer required to enable an InfoPath form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**.

SharePoint Designer and InfoPath are two different software applications.

Microsoft InfoPath is used designing, distributing, filling and submitting forms while SharePoint designer can be used for creating/modifying sites, workflows, pages, custom forms, etc.

You don't need SharePoint designer to create and publish InfoPath form to SharePoint List/Library.